# Non greedy matching using ? with grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm writing a bash script which analyses a html file and
I want to get the content of each single `<tr>...</tr>`. So my command looks like:

```
$ tr -d \\012 < price.html | grep -oE '<tr>.*?</tr>'
```

But it seems that `grep` gives me the result of:

```
$ tr -d \\012 < price.html | grep -oE '<tr>.*</tr>'
```

How can I make `.*` non-greedy?

Comment: The obligatory: [You can't parse html with regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you have `GNU Grep` you can use `-P` to make the match non-greedy:

```
$ tr -d \\012 < price.html | grep -Po '<tr>.*?</tr>'
```

The `-P` option enables Perl Compliant Regular Expression *(PCRE)* which is needed for non-greedy matching with `?` as Basic Regular Expression *(BRE)* and Extended Regular Expression *(ERE)* do not support it.

If you are using `-P` you could also use [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to avoid printing the tags in the match like so:

```
$ tr -d \\012 < price.html | grep -Po '(?<=<tr>).*?(?=</tr>)'
```

---

If you don't have `GNU grep` and the HTML is well formed you could just do:

```
$ tr -d \\012 < price.html | grep -o '<tr>[^<]*</tr>'
```

*Note: The above example won't work with nested tags within `<tr>`.*

Comment: The last example (using "[^<]*" is unlikely to work since there will inevitably be "td" or "th" tags within "tr".

Comment: @glennjackman good point, I will leave it in the answers however as the general principle might be useful to on lookers.

Answer (score 4):

Non-greedy matching is not part of the Extended Regular Expression syntax supported by `grep -E`. Use `grep -P` instead if you have that, or switch to Perl / Python / Ruby / what have you. (Oh, and `pcregrep`.)

Of course, if you really mean

```
<tr>[^<>]*</tr>
```

you should say that instead; then plain old `grep` will work fine.

You could (tediously) extend the regex to accept nested tags which are not `<tr>` but of course, it's better to use a proper HTML parser than spend a lot of time rediscovering why regular expressions are not the right tool for this.

Answer (score 3):

`.*?` is a Perl regular expression. Change your `grep` to

```
grep -oP '<tr>.*?</tr>'
```

Comment: Or, if he only wants the contents of the tr tag: `grep -oP '(?<=<tr>).*?(?=</tr>)'` -- using look-arounds to omit the actual tags

Answer (score 3):

Try perl-style-regexp

```
$ grep -Po '<tr>.*?</tr>' input
<tr>stuff</tr>
<tr>more stuff</tr>
```